# Correlate Performance counters and Exceptions in Application Insights for cloud service in OMS

Tags: azure, performancecounter, azure-application-insights, oms

I have one cloud service running on the server. Here is what I want, first thing, I want Performance counters for that cloud service and second thing, I want the exceptions occurred for that cloud service.
Currently, I am getting Performance counters when I go to Log Search in OMS using "Type=Perf" query. And exceptions data I am getting in Application Insights solution in OMS.
But I want this both data Performance counters and exceptions in a single place in OMS, and they must be correlated with each other, like which cloud service is running on which server and what amount of CPU it is using and what exceptions are there for that service.

Its difficult to correlate this data for me, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: With correlation you mean that you want to know specific performance counter values at the exact time an exception occurred or do you mean something else.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want performance counter of machine when requests are incoming/outgoing. I want to know which request is getting how much data in response and the response time, so that I can understand my server's performance. And I want to know if any request failed then I should know to which server/machine it was requesting.